# How to set image as wallpaper without causing OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have a straight-forward wallpaper app which I've just finished coding. I've used the tutorial here ( http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html ) to load the image on the screen at a lower resolution, while I use the code below to set the wallpaper. `imageId` represents the currently selected drawable.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Teamwork! Wallpaper set.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(
            MainActivity.this,
            "Damnit, clickers! Wallpaper wasn't set. Try killing and restarting the app?",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

However, I fear that the above code may cause phones of less memory to crash when it is called. Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening, or is there nothing to fear?

EDIT:

I used this code to display the images in the app:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public void setImage() {

    switch (imageNum) {

    case 1:

        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aaaae,
                options);
        display.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.aaaae, 300, 300));

        imageId = R.drawable.aaaae;

        break;

// Etc, etc.
    }
}
```

The method `setImage` is called every time the "Next" button is pressed.

Comment: "slow" and "memory" are in two different categories.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that. But why does everyone insist on downvoting my post? It's a genuine query, hardly a dumb question.

Comment: Receiving downvotes doesn't mean it's a "dumb" question, nor does it mean it's any less genuine. It simply means that it was either poorly worded, poorly formatted or is of very little help to others. In your case, I downvoted because you posted a hypothetical, not an actual issue. Your app seems to work, based on what you wrote, and you're asking for help with some abstract event which may or may not occur. Thus, it's really not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not handling images properly

Here is the solution to handle bitmaps in android
(This approach can handle 25000px by 25000px images in a non-ui thread.)

First, you should calculate the sampleBitmapSize of the bitmap ( to load the lower version of the same bitmap )

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
```

}
Below is the util function to calculate InSampleSize ( an integer that defines the value (rating) of quality of a bitmap).

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

Log.i("ImageUtil", "InSampleSize: "+inSampleSize);
return inSampleSize;
```

}

Comment: I made an edit :) I used similar code to display the image in the app, but how would I use it to show a high-definition wallpaper? My apologies, I'm still relatively new to coding.

Comment: I ask because the only thing which lowers the image's resolution in my code is setting the integer to 300 in the code "display.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
     getResources(), R.drawable.aaaae, 300, 300));". Should the 300 be replaced with another which takes into account how much the image should be scaled down?

Comment: 300 will be the height and width, if you wish to load the lower version of you image the above approach would work, but if you wish to load the Hi Resolution image (from the resource folder or some other source), it is not guaranteed that it will load properly on all device ( high chances of OutOfMemory Exceptions may occur).